# Allow non-admins to install fonts on Windows 7 without GPO

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, user-permissions

Is there a way in Windows 7 to allow users without admin rights to install fonts on their machine?

Our designers need to install new fonts regularly, but with no admin access, this means putting in an IT request every time.

In the long-term, the plan is to roll out a domain controller with GPO, but in the short term, is there a quick fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it can be accomplished with a GPO, it can be accomplished with local policy most likely. As an admin on the machine, open the MMC, add the group policy snap-in and choose to edit your local machine. How many machines are you needing to do this on?

Comment: I'll give this a go on Monday, and report back.